# What are some good books about the concept of 'logos' in ancient Greek philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, greeks

I am trying to do some reading on the concept of 'logos' in Greek philosophy before the time of Philo of Alexandria.  Every time I try to search for "Books about Logos" or even "Books about Greek Logos" I am flooded with books on how to design logos haha.

Comment: [Rescher, Cosmos and Logos. Studies in Greek Philosophy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cosmos_and_Logos/d-erjyNt2iAC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Comment: I would recommend primary sources. I think *Apology* by Plato might actually be the best place to warm up. Most of what you'll be able to find without more focus will descend from the Big 3 for which *Apology* is IMO the best entry point. Reading some [Heraclitus](https://fliphtml5.com/jmfd/opdc/basic) should help you with some pre-Socratic perspectives. But, I think part of the issue is that you're roughly asking after a survey of all of Greek philosophy, post-Socrates and pre-Philo.